# Running Jasmine tests automatically and continuously during development

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Are there any good strategies for running Jasmine tests automatically and continuously during development? Tests updating on file save should be good enough -- this might make any solution  less dependent on specific editors and/or other software required to detect non-saved changes.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby on Rails this is easy to setup with [jasminerice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) for the Jasmine setup and [guard-jasmine](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine) to automatically run the complete test suite on every file save. You can even add the [growl](https://github.com/visionmedia/growl) gem to enable [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to show the results of the automatic test runs with a small desktop notification when finished.